# Error Publishing my project with sFTP protocol

Tags: visual-studio-2019, clickonce

So, I've set up my publishing with the exact same data as my filezilla client, I made sure I wrote the same credentials and it stablishes connection with it since it asks for the login credentials, but once I put the login info and click on accept, publishing cancels and gives me an error: "Website cannot be created 'sftp://blablabla.com/folder'. The server connection timed out.

Any ideas what could it be?

Comment: Visual Studio does not support SFTP, it supports FTPS. They are very different protocols (SFTP is SSH, FTPS is _ye olde school_ FTP-over-TLS). Please clarify which you are using. Additionally, FTPS needs to know if it should be `PASSIVE` or not and has different port numbers.

Comment: I see, yeah, my server's ftp protocol is sFTP. I'll try to set it up so I can use ftps protocol then, than you.